# PySpark RDD MapPartition Tansformation

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

Why does `yield` work with `mapPartition` transformation, but `return` does not?

for example this works:

```py
def foo(x): yield max(x)
```

but this does not:

```
def foo(x): return max(x)
```

Comment: Hi MDHassan403, can you please be more specific about "not working" ?

Comment: I:m using mapPartition operation on a rdd to get the max of every partition however the function to get max value didn't work and throw a exception while the same can be acheived using generator